# Spouse joining business visitor to UK for part of trip

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, business-travel, spouses

I am applying for a UK business visa (6 months, multiple trips) via my organization. I will be staying for around 55 days during my first trip. I would like my wife to join me after 2-3 weeks of my travel.

When I am applying for my visa, what should I mention in the column where they ask *"Will my spouse be traveling with me to the UK?"*
She will not be traveling with me but she will join me after 2 weeks once she successfully processes her general visitor visa.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that technically the answer is NO: however there is a comments "additional information" field where I believe that it should be shared that spouse will be travelling independently on a date to join up with applicant for said period of time. Likewise comment should be made on spouse application "joining spouse already on business trip since date"